# find running total on every 7th day in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data like this. first column is the number of days from one starting point. second column is value generated after each number of days as given.
example after 1 day i get 5$, after 2nd day i get 3$ and so on. there may be some time where there is no revenue like 4th day. the numbers are not consecutive.

```
data =pd.DataFrame({'day':[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,17,18,19],
                   'value':[5,3,7,8,9,4,6,5,2,8,6,7,9,5,2]})
```

I want to find total value after every 7 day window. 
output should be like

```
day    value
7       36
14      27
21      23
```

I am using loop to achieve this. is there a better pythonic way of doing this.

```
df =pd.DataFrame({})
sum_value=0
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    sum_value+= row['value']
    if row['day'] %7==0:
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'day':row['day'],'sum_value':[sum_value]}))
        sum_value=0
pritn(df)
```

Also, how to find sum of previous 7 day values at each day (each row)
expected output

```
day   value
1      5
2      8
3      15
5      23
6      32
7      36
8      37
9      39
10     34
and so on...
```

I hope i did the calculation right. it is basically running total of previous 7 days of values. it would be easier if the numbers are not missing in days column.

Comment: Please check edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with helper `Series` with subtract 1 and integer division with aggregate `sum` and `last`:

```
df = data.groupby((data['day'] - 1) // 7 , as_index=False).agg({'day':'last', 'value':'sum'})
print (df)

   day  value
0    7     36
1   14     27
2   19     23
```

**Details**:

```
print ((data['day'] - 1) // 7)

0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    2
12    2
13    2
14    2
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

Similar solution if need divide `day` column by `7`:

```
df = data.groupby((data['day'] - 1) // 7)['value'].sum().reset_index()
df['day'] = (df['day'] + 1) * 7
print (df)

   day  value
0    7     36
1   14     27
2   21     23
```

EDIT: Need [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `sum`, but first is necessary add missing `dates` by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) - necessary unique values of `day` column.

```
idx = np.arange(data['day'].min(), data['day'].max() + 1)
df = data.set_index('day').reindex(idx).rolling(7, min_periods=1).sum()
df = df[df.index.isin(data['day'])]
print (df)
     value
day       
1      5.0
2      8.0
3     15.0
5     23.0
6     32.0
7     36.0
8     37.0
9     39.0
10    34.0
11    42.0
14    27.0
15    28.0
17    30.0
18    27.0
19    29.0
```

If get:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

it means duplicates `day` values and solution is aggregate `sum` first:

```
#duplicated day 1
data =pd.DataFrame({'day':[1,1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,17,18,19],
                   'value':[5,3,7,8,9,4,6,5,2,8,6,7,9,5,2]})


idx = np.arange(data['day'].min(), data['day'].max() + 1)
df = data.groupby('day')['value'].sum().reindex(idx).rolling(7, min_periods=1).sum()
df = df[df.index.isin(data['day'])]
print (df)
day
1      8.0
3     15.0
5     23.0
6     32.0
7     36.0
8     34.0
9     39.0
10    34.0
11    42.0
14    27.0
15    28.0
17    30.0
18    27.0
19    29.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```